# Access the properties window for a particular network connection

Tags: networking, windows-10, network-adapter

Given the name of a network connection, is there any way to bring up the properties page of only that network? The user should not be required to access ncpa.cpl, or navigate to the other network connections...

I can get a mini list of specific connection properties using netsh command, but a GUI and no shell access / batch file would be better.

If there is a single netsh command which gives me all the properties / value details for a specific connection, that might also come in handy.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe WMI or powershell can help.

Have a look at this [link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/using-powershell-to-find-connected-network-adapters/)

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)